# jQuery.ajax 'success' callback in chrome/chromium

Tags: jquery, ajax, nginx

I am using the nginx's upload progress module.

I need a JS function to GET the progress periodically.

I tried [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule#Usage_on_pure_JavaScript) (I changed the url path when I applied it on my server) but it does not work on chrome/chromium 12/13. (IE 8/9 Firefox 3+ OK. IE7 not tested)

I used Firebug to add some assertion, and found that the `onStateChange` is never called in chrome/chromium. (that is, the `readyState` is never 4)

Then I tried to rewrite the code in `$.ajax()`. The success callback is also never called (IE8/9 Firefox 3+ OK)

However, when I write some simple small ajax function to test in chrome/chromium, it's all right...

I need some hints.

Thank you for your time.

---

EDIT: When I use the function to send the ajax request manually in chrome's console, it is successful...

Comment: Adding some code we could look at would be helpful. Otherwise try using the `Network` tab in the Chrome Inspector to see what is the full request that is being sent on your ajax call, then paste that into a new browser window to see what you get. This may help in debugging as well.